# How to select options based on character user input stored in an array in C?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, input, character, strcmp

I may have worded that strange, but if you need clarification I can provide it. I'm a complete noob to coding and am learning to use C language.

I have printed out a menu of options for the user to select. The user input is read and stored into a character array. I then printed out the string back to the user. So far everything works to this point.

My issue is selecting an option based on this character input. 
I tried using strcmp inside if-else statements but never get the correct output.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: What does the 'never get the correct output' mean? If you want to compare strings in C, then strcmp is the way to go.

Comment: Example: if((strcmp(char_input,"colors"))==0){printf("Red, yellow, blue");}

Comment: When I run it, it goes to the else statement which I set to print "Error".

Comment: Yes that's right. The problem is that char_input might consist more characters than you are expecting. You need to make sure you don't include new lines, etc in "char_input". Use your debugger to see what it actually contains. How is your char_input defined and how do you read it?